# ံHow should I understand the following sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

In this following context, how should I understand the bold and italic part?

Context:

> This Dhamma is not something apart from oneself, but is closely
> associated with oneself. As such the Buddha exhorts: “***Abide with
> oneself as an island***, with oneself as a Refuge. Abide with the
> Dhamma as an island, with the Dhamma as a Refuge. Seek no external
> refuge.”

Source: Buddhism in a Nutshell

P. 24 By Nadara thera

Comment: Remain independent.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's yet more "unusual phrasing" from a *translated* text where both the concepts and the phrasing are inherently vague and imprecise.

Comment: Consider it *poetic* language. Start with something simpler, such as Joyce's *Finnegan's Wake*, before tackling this. ;-)

Comment: I see no reason to close this question. It's not all that unusual. We'd accept a question about a Jane Austen novel with language not all that different.

Answer (score 0):

> Abide with oneself as an island.

**To abide** is an old-fashioned / literary word for of  "stay" or "live".

**as** is a word that introduces a phrase of comparison or similarity.  Compare the word "like".

Live with yourself like [you are living on] an island.

I understand that to mean treat your self as if your person were an island and you are its only inhabitant. You yourself can be a refuge to which you can retreat, even though you may be living with others.

Comment: Thanks you so much, TimR.